# What is the common everyday term for people with front teeth moving forward?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

What is the common everyday term for people with front teeth moving forward as shown in the above picture, for example, "**she is buck-toothed**" or simply "**her teeth stick forward**"?

Comment: Call me mad, but the girl with the fringe (AmEng *bangs*) seems to have perfectly normal teeth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Buck-toothed" would be quite insulting if used to describe somebody. It also specifically means that the teeth are *angled* forwards, protruding. Another term for this is an *overbite* (eg "she has an overbite").

The people in the photographs don't look like their teeth are angled forwards - they simply have *prominent* (not protruding) teeth. We might say of them that they are "toothy", meaning their teeth are a prominent part of their facial features. We might also say they "have a toothy smile". People who show a lot of their gums when they smile are sometimes called "gummy". Again, all of these could be considered insulting as they are passing comment on a person's physical features.